# Add Tags to posts in ZF2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to implement Tags to my posts.  the user will input the tags in a textbox separated by commas.

```
        public function addAction() {
    $entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    $article = new Article;

    $form = new ArticleForm(); 
    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager,'CsnCms\Entity\Article'));
    $form->bind($article);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $post = $request->getPost();
        $form->setData($post);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->createTags($article, $post["Tags"]);
            $this->prepareData($article);
            $entityManager->persist($article);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('csn-cms/default', array('controller' => 'article', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
}
```

in the above code i have added a class called createTags that i am planning to split the inputted tags into an array and create a new tag entity for each and then store the  new tag entities in  a array in the article object.  Is this the correct way I should be doing this?

Comment: The way you doing things is certainly the way you need. I don't use Doctrine with ZF2 personally, but if I remember Symfony 2 I would say, it's ok. When I code the only questions I ask myself are : am I doing what I want to achieve, is my code testable enough to be sure that it is the expected behavior. Writing tests is the best way to be sure the code works the way you want, and be sure that the whole app won't do weird things because a variable is not correctly initialized during process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if the question want that detailed was just wondering if I should use a filter instead (I think this would work but dont know if it is good practice)

In the end I just use the processData function

```
   public function prepareData($article, $post) {

    $separator = ",";

    if($post['tagsString'] != "")
    {
        //Link Tags
        $array = array_unique(explode($separator, $post['tagsString']));
        foreach ($array as $tagString) {

            $tag = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Cms\Entity\Tag')->findOneBy(array('tag' => $tagString));

            $link = new \Cms\Entity\LinkTagToArticle($article, $tagString, $tag); 
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($link);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you wont be able search your pages based on tag if you store them in an array. you need to have a separated db table with columns like id,tag,pageId so you can properly search the pages with tag names.

Comment: He told nothing about doctrine db schema, I assume the schema is correct and his `Post` entity contains `Tags` by one-many or many-many relation. He certainly did not say that tags will be persisted as 'array' using serialization